# Unable to route Post Request with Large Request Body using Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to route a http post request using haproxy. I am routing the call on the basis of request body, so my acl logic in haproxy looks like: `acl api_name req.body -m reg "[0-something]-9[0-something]{2}"`.

But my post request body has more than 196975 characters, so haproxy is not able to apply acl logic on request body because it seems like the body is not processed completely, hence the regex did not match and i am getting error-code 503 (no server is available to handle this request) .

When i try the same acl logic on smaller request body my call gets routed correctly.How to make haproxy process the request bodies that are large.

I have added the configuration : option http-buffer-request, timeout http-request=1m and yet it is not working.

Comment: What is the encoding method?  In case of chunked-encoded body, currently only
the first chunk is analyzed.

Comment: @tetech I am using postman to hit the api, and postman only allows encoding : gzip, deflate, br. So no i am not sending data using chunked-encoding.

Comment: Show the HTTP request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the complete body has been received, by setting the HAProxy [option http-buffer-request](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4-option%20http-buffer-request)